# C# FormatException was unhandled while processing XML via DOM approach

Tags: c#, xml, dom, xml-parsing, formatexception

I've just started learning SAX/Stream as well as DOM approaches for parsing and processing XML files. My scenario would be that I am processing information from a given XML file that is retrieved from an FTP server which I hosted, put it into separate Array-lists before passing the lists into my DBManager to add them into a database. But, before I want to add it into the database, I want the user to press the "check button" to make sure the information is indeed correct before "adding to database". But that somehow triggers a FormatException. I do not see any "DateTime" in any of my classes or variables usage which confuses me even further.

EDIT 1: Thanks to Abdo Hussein, I realized the problem stated in the screenshot was that I was using **node**, not **node2**. However, the same problem applies to the following line and possibly the one after, too. Although they are still within the same loop as **node** and not **node2**.

```
invoice.ShippingCharges = Convert.ToDecimal(node.ChildNodes[4].InnerText);
invoice.InvoiceTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(node.ChildNodes[5].InnerText);
```

[image]

[image: FormatException was unhandled]

This is the pastebin code for this particular class, since it's too long and messy (I know, I'll leave it for later, I need to get past this first) http://pastebin.com/FewCm23W

Below will be the XML that I'm working on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Invoices>
  <Invoice ID="I001">    
    <InvoiceDate>21/06/2016</InvoiceDate>
    <SellerID>Supp001</SellerID>
    <BuyerID>WCS1810</BuyerID>
    <OrderID>Order001</OrderID>
    <InvoiceItem>
      <Product ID="R001">
        <ProductName>8GB RAM King</ProductName>
        <Description>RAM</Description>
        <Capacity>8GB</Capacity>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>100</UnitPrice>
      </Product>
    </InvoiceItem>
    <ShippingCharges>5</ShippingCharges>
    <InvoiceTotal>205</InvoiceTotal>
  </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

These are the classes for the different kind of information to be stored:

Invoice.cs

```
class Invoice
{
    public string InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public string SellerID { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemsTotalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingCharges { get; set; }
    //shippin charges + itemsTotalPrice
    public decimal InvoiceTotal { get; set; }
}
```

InvoiceItem

```
class InvoiceItem
{
    public string InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Capacity { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime is just a troubleshooting tip, doesn't mean you have a DateTime Format exception.

You are using **node** variable in your foreach not the **node2** , check this out.

Note that :-

1- FormatException  :value is not a number in a valid format.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw(v=vs.110).aspx

2- Check your CultureInfo as formats differ depends on different "CultureInfo"s

Comment: Care to specify which foreach?

Comment: Because I want to be able to calculate the value taken in node2 and store it in node

Comment: Aaah, after taking a break and working on something else and coming back, I saw where the node2 stupid mistake is. But the problem is that for these lines:

invoice.ShippingCharges = Convert.ToDecimal(node.ChildNodes[4].InnerText);
                invoice.InvoiceTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(node.ChildNodes[5].InnerText);

the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

Aah, I understand now.

Problem 1- node intead of node2 for each of the decimal variables that I'm converting.

```
foreach (XmlNode node2 in productList)
{
    decimal qty = Convert.ToDecimal(node.ChildNodes[3].InnerText);
    decimal unitpx = Convert.ToDecimal(node.ChildNodes[4].InnerText);
    totalItemPrice += (qty * unitpx);

}
```

Problem 2- I didn't know that the entire `InvoiceItem` was considered a childnode. So swapping my `[4]` and `[5]` to `[5]` and `[6]` worked.

```
invoice.ShippingCharges = Convert.ToDecimal(node.ChildNodes[5].InnerText);
invoice.InvoiceTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(node.ChildNodes[6].InnerText);
```